# Making a schedule ios app but don't understand how to do it

Tags: ios, json, xcode, schedule

For school I'm making an iOS app that includes a roster for a certain student. The student can login with an ID, and with that id the corresponding schedule is shown. So far the ID system is working. But I can't seem to figure out how to make the schedule part work. I have JSON data for every studentid, and want to filter this for every day but I honestly have no clue how to.

I'd love to get some help because I don't really have a clue how to do this.

Here is the code:

```
let url = URL(string: "(url)")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print ("ERROR")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    //Array
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSMutableDictionary
                    
                    let Days = myJson["Days"]  as! NSDictionary
                    let DayName = Days["Monday"]
                    print (DayName)
                    
                    
                }
                catch
                {
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Im currently getting a " Thread 8: signal SIGABRT " at "let Days = myJson["Days"]  as! NSDictionary"

and my console shows

> "Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x106520c30) to 'NSDictionary' (0x106521108)."

Would love to get some help as I have no clue how to fix this

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: The value for key `Days` is an array, not a dictionary and any casting to `NSMutableArray/Dictionary...` in Swift is nonsensical anyway.

Comment: Im sorry I have no experience with swift/xcode whatsoever. What am I supposed to change it to?

Comment: What does `Days` really contain? Array of strings or what?

Comment: I want a way to be able to ask for example Monday, and then only get the info from monday, me and a friend tried figuring it out and we stopped after a while and left with this

Comment: It was originally like this                         `let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSMutableDictionary
 print (myJson)` after that I tried printing just one day, and then it got messed up

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a type alias for convenience

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]
```

The line `if let content = data` is not needed, if `error` is not `nil` `data` is guaranteed to be not `nil`.

This prints `StudentName`, the day names and the values for keys `Classroom`, `Name` and `Teacher` of the lessons:

```
   do {
      if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data!, options: []) as? JSONDictionary {
        print(json["StudentName"] as! String)
        if let days = json["Days"] as? [JSONDictionary] {
            for day in days {
                print(day["DayName"] as! String)
                if let lessons = day["Lessons"] as? [JSONDictionary] {
                    for lesson in lessons {
                        let classRoom = lesson["Classroom"] as! String
                        let name = lesson["Name"] as! String
                        let teacher = lesson["Teacher"] as! String

                        print(classRoom, name, teacher)
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
  } catch {
    print(error)
  }
```

Comment: It works! Now would it be possible to convert all days into a UITableView? Or what would be the best way to display it?

Comment: It's always good practice to create custom structs or classes for the objects.

Comment: So I would have to create a class for every day?

Comment: It depends on the model structure. I'd use at least a class `Lesson` with all parameters and maybe a class `Student` with `name : String`, `class : String` and `days : [Day]` properties and a `Day` class containing `name : String` and `lessons : [Lesson]`.

Comment: Would you be able to give an example ? I don't really understand

Comment: It's pretty straightforward and there are hundreds of questions and reasonable answers regarding parsing JSON into custom classes here on SO.

Comment: Alright I will look into it. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Okay honestly I've searched for a while but I just can't figure it out. Could you please help. How do I make it so that I can put the data into a Table View, and that it changes per ID filled in? I have a save button at the login page and the id that is being filled in gets saved. I just don't understand the rest

Comment: How exactly do I take just one day instead of all 5? Currently every day gets printed but I want to get only 1 of the 5